# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead PCA Array Issue

Tags: python, spyder, k-means

I fixed the code for the first part but now the PCA is having issue with the array so everything until the #%% is good.. ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1.67240605 1.60913446 1.68764392 ... 3.58612338 4.80310774 3.67385456].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

```
data = sns.load_dataset('iris', delimiter= ',')
data = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2], "B": [3.0, 4.5]})
data.to_numpy()
X1 = np.random.normal(size=1000, loc=1,scale=1)
Y1 = np.random.normal(size=1000, loc=1,scale=1)
X2 = np.random.normal(size=1000, loc=4,scale=1)
Y2 = np.random.normal(size=1000, loc=4,scale=1)

X= np.concatenate([X1,X2])
Y = np.concatenate([Y1, Y2])
XY = np.vstack([X,Y]).T

plt.scatter(X,Y)
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
km= KMeans(n_clusters=3)
km.fit(XY)
cluster_labels = km.predict(XY)
colors = ('red', 'blue', 'green')
plt.scatter(X,Y,c=cluster_labels,cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors))
print(km.cluster_centers_)
plt.scatter(km.cluster_centers_[:,0],km.cluster_centers_[:,1],c='black',marker='x')
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
#%%
pca = PCA(n_components=2)
X2d = pca.fit_transform(X)
fig = plt.figure()
colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green']
plt.scatter(X2d[:,0],X2d[:,1],c=Y,cmap=matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors))
plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Katherine, I did not understand your issue. I tried running the code you provided with the proper libraries and I found no error on it. Can you give more details about it?

Comment: There is only a small typo in your code: `data.to_numpy()` returns a value and therefore it's not being assigned to anything. You can change it to `data = data.to_numpy()`. Besides that I've tried to run it and haven't found no error in it too.

Comment: So even with the data = data.to_numpy() I'm still getting the type error. @GabrielMelodePaula I'm trying to use KMeans with the iris data set from seaborn here's part of the assignment "Fit the data points to their corresponding clusters and compute the mean sepal width,
sepal length, petal width, and petal length of data within each cluster." I just didn't want to post the question because I'm not trying to get anyone to do my homework for me I'm just stuck

Comment: @Katherine for the new error you need to fit the PCA on `XY` data instead of `X`. This error is happening because you are trying to make decomposition of a single feature, which is impossible, the PCA expects 2 or more features, in case `XY`. Just change it to `X2d = pca.fit_transform(XY)`

Comment: Thank you @GabrielMelodePaula